# How to extract URLs from many lines in a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How Can i use the extractor when I am using more than one element to extract.

I have got a excel sheet in my dataframe and I want to extract all the URLs in the dataframe2.Comment.

I use this:

```py
from urlextract import URLExtract
extractor = URLExtract()
dataframe2.Comment = extractor.find_urls(dataframe2.Comment)
```

And I get error:

> expected string or bytes-like object

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you need to apply the extractor over each individual value of the column rather than the column as a whole.

```
from urlextract import URLExtract

extractor = URLExtract()
dataframe2.Comment = dataframe2.Comment.apply(extractor.find_urls)
```

Comment: Hi That works thank you. Now i need to Cut all the [] out of my dataframe. The function dataframe2['Comment'] = dataframe2.Comment.str.replace('[]','') does not work. I get  error unterminated character set at position 0! Can you help me with this please?